# What's the best way to use offline Firestore with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore, offline, create-react-app

**tl;dr**  Is it a good practice to update redux store before trying to update a backend db (e.g. Firestore), or is there another "best practice" solution out there?

At present, I've got an app created with create react app.  Back end data is stored on Firestore.  When the app loads, initially, it fetches an array of projects from Firestore and loads them into a Redux store that the UI uses to render content.

That's all well and fine.

My question is about how to implement CRUD actions when offline (e.g. creating a project).  For the record, CRA is caching the app so the UI works offline (if there's data in the store), so my question is not about that, it's about the order in which it's best send data to Firebase and dispatch the (same) payload to the redux store.

Note that "db" in the below is a Firestore connected database (configured elsewhere), and when I talk about using Firestore offline, I'm talking about enablePersistence, which is default of iOS and Android.  And I'm using Thunk.

For example, I see a common Redux action creator pattern that looks like the below.  In this case I'm using it to create a new project:

```
export const createProject = projectData => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: CREATE_PROJECT_START });
  try {
    await db
      .collection("projects")
      .doc(projectData.project_uid)
      .set({ ...projectData });
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_PROJECT_SUCCESS, payload: projectData });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_PROJECT_FAIL, payload: e.message });
  }
};
```

The behavior is such that the dispatch of the payload to Redux does not happen until the promise comes back from Firebase.

In testing this, I can turn off the network and create a new project.  When the createProject function is called (by a form submit), the console lights up with net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED messages, which is expected behavior.

However, when the user is returned from the form to a page that renders all projects, the new project is not rendered because the Firebase promise has not yet completed.

Awesomely, however, when I flick the network back on (I've only tested this for a few minutes and I'm not sure how well this would work after a long period of time), Firebase will catch on to the fact that it's online, send the data, return the promise, and then the dispatch to Redux can occur.

While awesome, it's not the best user experience, so I've implemented a small tweak shown below:

```
export const createProject = projectData => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: CREATE_PROJECT_START });
  try {
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_PROJECT_SUCCESS, payload: projectData });
    await db
      .collection("projects")
      .doc(projectData.project_uid)
      .set({ ...projectData });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_PROJECT_FAIL, payload: e.message });
  }
};
```

By simply moving the dispatch to Redux **before** calling the set method on the db, the behavior is much better in that the project renders immediately to the user after creation in the UI.  The user can, in fact, perform several changes which are all reflected correctly in the UI, even though the db is working offline.

The errors still go off in the console, again expected.  And when the network connection is re-established, Firestore does receive the data in the background.

So, having said all that, is it a good/bad practice to put the dispatch to Redux before the db update, and/or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think what you've essentially done here is what Apollo calls an 'Optimistic UI' - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/optimistic-ui#optimistic-basics.

Answer (score 1):

Bumped into this question myself recently and did the wrong thing initially, so while the pain/lesson is still fresh.

The sync model that Firestore uses is one where the Promise's resolution is intended to provide the developer with an opportunity to handle rejection failures; be it immediately, or at some point in the future when the app comes back online e.g. gives the dev an opportunity to retry or rollback a change.

To use this error handling mechanism effectively leads to a state model whereby the apps local state has to lead the central state.

To answer the question about Redux best practise. As long as its Reducers' remain "Pure", when external side-effects occur relative to local state manipulation doesn't matter.

Many of the various Redux async middleware solutions run at different points relative to the Reducers, e.g. Thunks and Sagas before, Epics afterwards, Loops with. I think it just feels a bit odd because it's not what we're used to using. Essentially though, when it happens is whatever makes the most sense to the developer for the use case at hand.

I'd guess the question author cracked this one a while back. However, once Firestore's sync model is understood there's still how to best handle rejections, performance offline with potentally a large number of queued Promises, dealing with backend writes that fail when there are no Promises because the app's been restarted etc etc.

Would be very interested in experience and pointers to implementing that stuff :-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  On this one (and others), I wound up writing to redux first, attempting the firestore operation, and then handling errors if they arose from the firestore operation, reversing the operation in redux and informing the user in the GUI of the failure.